# ubuntu live usb not detected by UEFI secure boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

Even though I created an UEFI Ubuntu Live USB, I am only able to boot from this when I disable secure boot.

I would like to fix this because I don’t want to have to disable secure boot in order to access my live usb. Also, if I were to install Ubuntu, this will mean it’s not in secure boot mode.

All I did was use Unetbootin on Ubuntu then Rufus on windows and Startup Disk Creator to create the live usb. Neither of these methods got a usb to boot when I set my laptop to secure boot. I used a GPT partition scheme too.

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What is the source of Ubuntu ISO? Does your PC's UEFI require you to first load the factory keys when you enable Secure Boot, from within the setup?  Did you try any other distro like Linux Mint for example? Is Windows 10 installer booting fine with the same setup? What happens if you do not use any third-party tools and just expand the ISO on GPT scheme FAT32 formatted pen drive and try to boot?

Answer (score 0):

try forcing a specific media to boot or enter the bios and disable secure boot. you don't need it.